# What is the safest way to replace text matching a specific pattern in a remote file through SSH/sFTP with Python3 and make sure it is closed?

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I need to replace a value in a remote text file. This mostly works but recently I encountered an issue where a .swp of the remote file being processed ("script.sh" in example below) has been left in the wild and the whole programm was stuck (Python script is launched by a Jenkins pipeline by the way).

This likely means that the file being processed was never closed properly and eventually freezed the subsequent remote execution of the modified script file.

What would be the safest way to replace text in a remote Bash script file and make sure it is closed properly before executing?

**Actual code:**

```
server = "server.tld"    
ssh_user = "foo"   
ssh_keypath = "/home/foo/.ssh/rsa_01"
ssh_pass = "ZZZZZZZ" 
ssh_client = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())   

try:
    ssh_client.connect(server,port=ssh_port,username=ssh_user, key_filename=ssh_keypath,passphrase=ssh_pass)        
except Exception as e:
    msg = "An error occured on remote server {} : {}"
    logger.error(msg.format(server,str(e)))

sftp_client = ssh_client.open_sftp()

tmp_sh_path = "/opt/dir/tmp/script.sh"

# Replacing text in script file
with sftp_client.open(tmp_sh_path,mode="r+") as remote_sh_file:

    try:
        lines = remote_sh_file.readlines()
        remote_sh_file.seek(0)
        
        for line in lines:

            if line.startswith("export ORACLE_HOME="):
                remote_sh_file.write("export ORACLE_HOME={}\n".format("/oracle/app/product/X.X.X"))
            else:
                remote_sh_file.write(line)
                     
    except Exception as e:
        msg = "An error occured when editing script file {} on remote server {} : {}"
        logger.error(msg.format(tmp_sh_path,server,str(e)))          
    finally:
        remote_sh_file.close() 

logger.info("File editing seems to be performed properly on remote server")

# Edited script execution
ssh_cmd_exec_script = "cd {}; ./{} foo".format(os.path.dirname(tmp_sh_path),os.path.basename(tmp_sh_path))

# Stuck at this point
cmd_exec_script = ssh_exec(ssh_client=ssh_client,cmd=ssh_cmd_exec_script,spool=True)
```

Comment: You can't be sure to properly close a file on a remote system (e.g. network error). However you can create a modified copy of `script.sh` in the temp (with random name) and when you're done just move it and replace the original file.

Comment: @János Roden: Perhaps I've been a bit definitive in asking for "making sure", I meant at least is the current implementation sufficiently robust (aka the try/catch/finally close())? Of course has you mentionned I can't seek for certainty regarding an eventual network issue